# Jenkins Kicking off Downstream Jobs

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees

I have a Project A. Project A is listed as dependency in Project B. Whenever I kick off build of project A in Jenkins, once the build is successful, it is kicking of Project B automatically. Is there any way I can stop this or can add a parameter for this step?

Comment: Break the dependency?

Comment: Hello @towel, If I break the dependency, project B is not going to have a successful build.

Comment: I would say you should rely on Project A's artifacts to determine whether you can run Project B or not. Could you provide the code in which you start the build of both projects?

Comment: I added <disableTriggerDownstreamProjects>${disableTriggerDownstreamProjects}</disableTriggerDownstreamProjects> in the job config and added another parameter to the job. Will update once I check the job

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I understand you don't use pipelines. I assumed the usage of pipelines because of the `jenkins-pipeline` tag. If you use a freestyle job your best option is to use a conditional step in Project B that verifies Project A was built in some way.

Comment: That was my mistake. Yes, I am not using pipeline and am using jobs created out of a job template.